# Turn Off/Lock Screen - Without Launching the Activity - Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen, launching-application

I am developing a simple screen lock application.

I want that when I click on the app icon the screen gets locked and turns off. And am also able to do that, **BUT** before locking the screen the **main activity gets launched** (Set to Theme.NoDisplay) which takes time to get the device locked, which I don't want to happen.

So is there a way that I can turn off my screen (OR do something like starting Torch) without launching the app activity. If required I can also provide the code which i am with.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [android widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

Comment: No it should be an application and not a widget.